# Cannot find the source of this "Classroom of the Elite: Year 2" manga panel

Tags: classroom-of-the-elite

*Classroom of the Elite: Year 2* Room1 is released, but I can't find it on the internet. I found some images which show it's released but didn't find the source.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: As usual, note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 3):

**The serialization of the manga adaptation of *Classroom of the Elite: Year 2* was just started on December 25, 2021, on [*monthly comic alive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monthly_Comic_Alive) [issue 2/2022](https://comic-alive.jp/magazine/alive-8006.html).**

[image]

[image]

The magazine has not been licensed (officially translated) anywhere. [Japanese Book Walker](https://bookwalker.jp/de5ad15f1c-4f18-4247-82ab-3a590e0001c6) sells the digital version. Other than that, it is only available as a print version on [a variety of Japanese online bookshops](https://www.kadokawa.co.jp/product/322012000765/).

As with the common practice of manga serialization, there will be no tankobon version until enough chapters from the magazines are collected.

---

References:

- [The manga adaptation of *Classroom of the Elite: Year 2* begins, the main story of *Himawari-san* enters the final chapter](https://natalie.mu/comic/news/459365) (Japanese)